# Powershell Remove-WmiObject: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: path

Tags: windows, powershell, service

```
$binaryPath = "aValidPath"
$user = "aUser"
$passwrd = "aPassword"

$serviceName = "aService"

if (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    # using WMI to remove Windows service because PowerShell does not have CmdLet for this
    $serviceToRemove = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='$serviceName'"
    $serviceToRemove | Stop-Service
    Remove-WmiObject $serviceToRemove 
}

$secured = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwrd -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $secured)

New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $creds
```

Everytime I try to execute this code I get:

```
Remove-WmiObject: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: path
```

And I can't figure out why.

If you hover over "$serviceToRemove" you get:

```
\\*redacted*\root\cimv2:Win32_Service.Name="*redacted*"
PSComputerName:"*redacted*"
RunspaceId:*redacted*
PSShowComputerName:$false
```

the $binaryPath is absolute accurate, as the "New-Service" portion uses it just fine.  Remove won't remove the service though cause of that error. And $serviceToRemove.delete() doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single example website I can find says to use this:

```
Remove-WmiObject $serviceToRemove
```

or

```
$serviceToRemove.delete()
```

the way I fixed this script was by using this syntax instead

```
Remove-WmiObject -path $serviceToRemove
```

I recently updated everything to the latest Powershell versions and am using the latest "Visual Studio Code" for this.  Note: I got the same error messages using the oldschool ISE.